# Multiple Dropdowns Lists and Removing Value Of Observable Array On Select

Tags: knockout.js

I have a situation where I have multiple dropdowns on my page sharing the same observable array.  Lets say `5 dropdowns lists`, bound to an `observable array` of `[1,2,3,4,5]` with a `optionsCaption` of `- Game -` .  After they select a value, I would like the other dropdown lists to remove that item from their list.  So if `dropdown 1` selected `2`, all the other dropdowns would show `1,3,4,5`, and if they select `- Game -` again, all dropdwons go back to their original state.

Answer (score 0):

They'll have to have separate data sources since they have different data. Two ways I can think of to do this:

Have one array of all choices, and computed arrays for each select - each containing the contents of the choices array minus the selected option from the other selects.

You could also have each select's options be an observable array, and then on select you call remove on every other option with the selected item, and push the old value to every other select box. You would make this happen with subscribe.